# How can I allow HTML links in translated strings?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I created a custom D8 module with all text strings declared in English, either via this->t(), t() or in various configuration (YML) files.

I am now in the process of translating those strings in French so that I can then extract them and package them with the module.

My issue: some strings for the interface contain HTML links (mostly refering to other Drupal admin pages); they display and work fine in English, but when I try to translate those strings via the Drupal UI, I get an error saying *"The submitted string contains disallowed HTML"*. If I remove the `<a>` then the error disappears.

Here's an example of a string containing several links:

```
$this->t('<p>Some explanations here. You can find a more information 
  <a href=@hhelp>on the help page</a>.<br>Note: after changing this value, 
  you may have to <a href=@hperformance>clear the cache</a> for this setting 
  to take effect.</p>', array(
  '@hhelp' => '../../help/mymodule',
  '@hperformance' => '../development/performance',
)),
```

Is it possible to translate those strings while keeping the links in the translation? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the absence of the quotes. I try to insert this traslation on a drupal site and it work!

```
<p>Some explanations here. You can find a more information 
 <a href='@hhelp'>on the help page</a>.<br>Note: after changing this 
  value,you may have to <a href='@hperformance'>clear the cache</a> 
  for this setting to take effect.</p>
```

It also work with `"`

Comment: You're right, thanks. That was a really silly mistake. Weird that it works without the quote, though (in the PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried split the string as below

```
$text = t('Some explanations here. You can find a more information 
<a href="@hhelp">on the help page</a>.', array('@hhelp' =>'../../help/mymodule',));

$text.= t('<br>Note: after changing this value, you may have to <a href="@hperformance">
clear the cache</a> for this setting 
to take effect.', array('@hperformance' => '../development/performance',));
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is _not_ because there are two links. It also occurs when there's only one link. (Problem solved though, it was because of missing quotes around the href value.)